# How to insert a row when data doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have below data set , where there is no data for New york on 1/18 and no data for Rio on 2/18.

```
City    NoOfRecords    Date 
Paris     15           1/16/2018
Rio       20           1/16/2018
Munich    10           1/16/2018
New York  25           1/16/2018
Paris     15           1/18/2018
Rio       20           1/18/2018
Munich    10           1/18/2018
Paris     15           2/18/2018
New York  20           2/18/2018
Munich    10           2/18/2018
```

How ever, for my report I need to have a row with 0 records for new york and Rio on 1/18 and 2/28 respectively and expected out put shoud be like below:

```
City    NoOfRecords    Date 
Paris     15           1/16/2018
Rio       20           1/16/2018
Munich    10           1/16/2018
New York  25           1/16/2018
Paris     15           1/18/2018
Rio       20           1/18/2018
Munich    10           1/18/2018
New York  0            2/18/2018
Paris     15           2/18/2018
New York  20           2/18/2018
Munich    10           2/18/2018
Rio       0           2/18/2018
```

How do i insert a row each time there is no record dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to create a subset of cities and dates, and `join` that to your actual table. Usually you would use a calendar table but here, you seem to only want dates where at least 1 city had a record.

```
declare @table table (city varchar(64), NoOfRecords int, [Date] date)
insert into @table
values
('Paris',15,'1/16/2018'),
('Rio',20,'1/16/2018'),
('Munich',10,'1/16/2018'),
('New York',25,'1/16/2018'),
('Paris',15,'1/18/2018'),
('Rio',20,'1/18/2018'),
('Munich',15,'1/18/2018'),
('Paris',15,'2/18/2018'),
('New York',20,'2/18/2018'),
('Munich',30,'2/18/2018')

select distinct
    x.city
    ,coalesce(t.NoOfRecords,0)
    ,x.Date
from (
        select 
            distinct x.city, y.Date
        from @table x
        cross apply (select distinct date from @table) y
        )  x
left join
    @table t on t.city =
```

Or with a `cross join` in the derived table.

```
select distinct
    x.city
    ,coalesce(t.NoOfRecords,0)
    ,x.Date
from (
        select 
            distinct x.city, y.Date
        from @table x
        cross join @table y
        )  x
left join
    @table t on t.city = x.city and t.Date = x.Date
```

Comment: thank you very much.. this works. but my data set is really huge.. will cross apply cause performance issue?

Comment: Usually not. Naturally indexes, server settings, and many other factors come into play with performance.